# How would i find this position function?

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification

So this is the text of the question
**In a free-fall experiment, an object is dropped from a height of h = 256 feet. A camera on the ground 500 ft from the point of impact records the fall of the object. Find the position function that yields the height of the object at time t assuming the object is released at time t = 0**

How would i determine the position function it is asking for ? I have the answer which is $-16t^2+256$ but how would i get that?

Comment: There is a typo, set t = 0 and note the height mismatch.

Comment: thank you about that i had placed the incorrect value but the question still stands.

Comment: You tagged "solution-verification" but you provided no attempt at a solution? Please read the relevant (free-fall under gravity without air resistance) section in your physics notes. Or derive it at once by integrating the acceleration due to gravity g [m/s^2] twice to obtain position [m]. (Hint. Initial velocity $v_0$, i.e. the constant of first integral, equals zero.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, the object in free fall is under gravitational acceleration $g=9.81\ m/s^2$

Let any any time $t$, $h$ be the height of the object (initially at a height $h_0=256$ feet) from the ground (point of impact). Then the acceleration is given as $$\frac{d^2h}{dt^2}=g$$ By integrating w.r.t. $t$ we get
$$\frac{dh}{dt}=\int gdt=gt+C\tag 1$$  integrating (1) w.r.t. $t$ we get 
$$\int \frac{dh}{dt}dt=\int (gt+C)dt$$
$$h=\frac{1}{2}gt^2+Ct+D\tag 2$$
Now, applying the following conditions

1. at time $t=0$, the velocity of the object $v=\frac{dh}{dt}=0$ hence setting the values in (1), we get $$0=g(0)+C\implies C=0$$
2. at time $t=0$, the height $h=256$ hence setting the values in (2), we get
   $$256=\frac{1}{2}g(0)^2+(0)(0)+D\implies D=256$$
   Hence, setting the values in (2), the height (position function) of the object any any time $t$ from the ground is given as $$\color{red}{h=\frac{1}{2}gt^2+256}$$